# Jquery Ajax Call returns undefined but in Mozilla developer tool I can see the response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http

I am sending an jquery ajax call using the code below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#clickme').click(function () {
            var contenValue = $('#content').val();


            var response = $.ajax({
                'url': 'URL',
                'type': 'GET',
                'crossDomain': true,                    
                'dataType': 'jsonp',
                'contentType': 'application/json',
                'async':false
            }).responseText;

            console.log(response);


        })
    });
```

but in the console I am getting the result as 'undefined' but in the developer tools of the mozilla under Response I can see the output as

[image]

Comment: @empiric - a syncrhonous $.ajax would have a responseText property (I believe)

Comment: @JaromandaX yes you're right, depending on what the request on the server side returns. never used that though

Comment: just noticed another thing ... `datatype:'jsonp'` ... this combination of flags is strange ... @empiric, you're right, as this is a (cross domain) request for `jsonp` the returned (async:false) object can not have responseText property, as JSONP is achieved by adding a script tag to the DOM ...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong due to `ajax()` will return a Promise.

```js
var response = $.ajax({
     'url': 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
     'type': 'GET',
     'crossDomain': true,                    
     'dataType': 'jsonp',
     'contentType': 'application/json'
    }).then(function(res) {
        console.log(res) //this is your result
})
var response = $.ajax({
    'url': 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
    'type': 'GET',
    'crossDomain': true,                    
    'dataType': 'jsonp',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'async':false,
    success: function (result) {
      console.log(result)
    },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ajax actually returns a jqXHR object, which is a superset of (native) XMLHttpRequest object - which includes `then` method, so, yes, it is a promise of sorts. The real issue is that `async:false` makes no sense with `dataType:'jsonp'`, there can be no *synchronous* responseText when using `jsonp` - so, in essence, your answer is correct, but not for the reason you give :p

Comment: async false makes no sense with JSONP at all - it's not *wrong*, it's just *ignored* -as you can see, the code works equally with or without it